# 434MHz PCB Trace Antenna Design

Tags: rf, antenna, fcc, pcb-antenna

Can anyone provide a reference design for a 434 MHz PCB Trace Antenna? Is it just a matter of creating a snake trace pattern about 17cm long and slapping a ground plane under it (with a trace thickness for say 50 ohms characteristic impedance to the ground plane given the PCB thickness)?

The context is that I think I'm heading toward using a trace antenna with the RFM12B transceiver module en route to passing regulatory standards. I've been told that embedding the antenna in the PCB is an easier / lower cost path to certification than allowing for a whip (or other externally connected) antenna. Any advice or pointers would be most appreciated!

Comment: you asking about a Fractal antenna ?I have seen a java based simulator for that.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Tye following may be useful.
Most are 2.4 GHz focused but should provide some useful ideas.

[TI 2.4 GHz PCB Antenna - AN 043](http://www.ti.com/lit/an/swra117d/swra117d.pdf) - 2.4 GHz but should have significant value.

[Compact Integrated antennas - Freescale AN 2731](https://www.nxp.com/docs/en/application-note/AN2731.pdf) - significant relevance

[A few zillion PCB antennas - all images linked to webpages](https://www.google.co.nz/search?q=pcb+antenna&hl=en&safe=off&prmd=imvns&tbm=isch&tbo=u&source=univ&sa=X&ei=lrKaT_uyLcqjiQe2o6jcDg&ved=0CFQQsAQ&biw=1745&bih=982)

[Commercial products - but some good idea starters](http://www.wa5vjb.com/)

[Inverted F design - 2.4 GHz but significant relevance](https://www.semanticscholar.org/paper/Analysis-and-design-of-an-inverted-F-antenna-on-a-Soras-Karaboikis/68500adca93f4462b94c1f3092dcc4027cc8d1f9)
title: "Analysis and Design of an Inverted F Antenna Printed on a PCMCIA Card for the 2.4 GHz ISM band.pdf"

Wow [Another inverted F design paper - looks superb](http://www.wless.ru/files/ZigBee/EM250/120-5052-000_Designing_with_a_PCB_Antenna.pdf)

**NO** PCB antennas here BUT [many432 MHz antennas](http://www.dxzone.com/catalog/Antennas/70cm/)

Comment: The third link is GIYF. Which [isn't appreciated](http://meta.electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/1068/whats-the-value-of-giyf) much here.

Comment: @FedericoRusso - Many are likely to appreciate the retrospectively obvious but massively valuable insight that using images linked to web vastly improves the ability to locate pertinent information. I add such a link to many of my answers because I believe that it is nonintuitive BUT liable to vastly improve the value that people get from search engines. | EDITED 2022 to remove some snark :-) :-(

Comment: @FedericoRusso - please to see the response that I have added to the question which you cite above. As noted t here, a modicum, or even a soupcon,  of common sense is required.

Answer (score 6):

From [this document](http://wireless.murata.com/media/products/apnotes/antenna.pdf):

> *One big advantage for the short whip is that it can be a trace
>   on a PCB, with a chip inductor used to tune out the
>   capacitive reactance of the antenna. If the trace runs parallel
>   to ground, the real part of the antenna impedance will be
>   approximately 10 ohms. In a hand-held unit, the impedance
>   will be raised substantially through hand effects. For a tenth
>   wavelength strip on a board with hand effects included, the
>   antenna has a capacitive reactance of about 150 ohms. At
>   433.9 MHz, this would require a 56 nH inductor to cancel
>   the capacitive reactance of the 2.7 inch (70 mm) long line.*

[image]

The document also describes spiral, chip and loop antennas (a.o.).

Comment: Is that software defined antenna's are on the market ?