# Determining the transmit frequency of a key fob

Tags: frequency, 433mhz

How can I determine the frequency of this RF module (car keyfob?)

It should be 433 or 315 MHz.

I have a 50MHz digital oscilloscope.

Is there a way?

[image: 1]

[image: 2]

Comment: Not without some external hardware.  Is your 'scope digital or analog?

Comment: this may help... https://duckduckgo.com/?q=sdr+dongle&ia=web

Comment: the scope is digital

Comment: you could try to jam its tranmission with another fob of known frequency, try with 433 and 315, and see which succeeds at jamming.

Answer (score 5):

Almost certainly 315MHz.

1. There isn't a visible crystal on the PCB. The 433MHz frequency used is actually just one frequency at 433.82MHz as defined by the FCC and numerous other agencies throughout the world. To transmit with adequate accuracy always requires a crystal, an IC by itself can't do it.

A device using "315MHz" actually just has to fit in a band that goes all the way from 270MHz up to 390MHz so accuracy to keep within the band is not a problem, but it has to be accurate enough to stay within the acceptable range of the receiver which depends on its design. A simple super-regenerative receiver has a wide acceptance range.

A superhet receiver has a much-narrower bandwidth but some receivers are designed to sweep over a range to make them compatible with transmitters that are not very accurate (such as this one).

2. Asking Google to search "6sc2 remote" comes up with a number of links that are all pointing to 315MHz devices. Unfortunately no datasheets.

Comment: The TinySA spectrum analyzer (the Ultra, at least) does a great job of finding frequencies like this; I just checked out the three keyfobs here at the house, and it showed two were at 433 MHz and one is at 313 MHz

Answer (score 3):

That gold-plated outer ring is very likely resonant at the transmitting frequency. Since this loop also includes a capacitor, loop perimeter length gives an uncertain indication of frequency.

That outer gold transmitting loop *might* be able to couple enough power into **Lecher wires** so that you can measure wavelength with a simple diode detector. Lecher wire lengths will have to be long enough to accommodate the lowest frequency (315 MHz) whose wavelength is about one meter.
This technique is crude, but should be able to discriminate between 315MHz and 433 MHz. It is so simple, that it might be worth a try. Plenty of web resources show how the technique works. The key fob may not transmit enough power for this to work, and it may transmit for such a short period that it will be difficult to find nulls/peaks along the wires...hopefully a key press keeps transmitting.
[image: lecher wire coupling to key fob]

Comment: That’s a neat trick and new to me - thanks! Here are two links to explanations of the method: https://hackaday.com/2017/02/07/using-a-lecher-line-to-measure-high-frequency/ and https://rimstar.org/equip/lecher_line.htm

Answer (score 1):

Does it have an FCC ID? You should be able to find details in the FCC database. That said, the ‘CE’ mark is fake. It’s the ‘China Export’ film-flam that unscrupulous manufacturers use.

Answer (score 1):

This isn’t foolproof, but low tech: Carefully measure the total length of the antenna to millimeter accuracy, taking into account its curvature.

You can then refer to existing PCB antenna specs (e.g., [434MHz PCB Trace Antenna Design](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/30822/434mhz-pcb-trace-antenna-design)) and antenna calculators (e.g., https://www.omnicalculator.com/physics/dipole) to approximate the frequency that might correspond to your measured length. Note that for a fob this small, you might want to consider 1/8 wavelength rather than 1/4 (just divide the 1/4 wavelength number in half).

PCB antenna design depends on many variables (e.g., https://www.cypress.com/file/136236/download), including **trace width** and **thickness**, the former of which you can measure but the latter would be tricky, along with the **substrate dielectric constant**, which you can assume is probably the typical ~4.4 for the FR4 I presume this is printed on. So there’s a lot of variability here and it’s unlikely that the number for a dipole aerial antenna will match the number for a PCB trace antenna, but maybe it’s enough to determine whether it’s a 315 or 433 MHz resonance.

Answer (score 0):

Without looking up the ID, you're in "can't get there from here" territory.  Build, buy or borrow a faster scope, or a spectrum analyzer, or a receiver that covers 433 to 315MHz.

Comment: notice that an RTL-SDR stick for 10$ from China might do, even without an antenna, at close range, to build up enough spectrum analyzing capabilities to answer the question of "which band".